# Angular pipe is blocking a template function execution

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app that takes an array of objects and sorts the data in either ascending or descending order by an object property value using the template function `sortByField()`. The app can also filter out data so that if a user types in a search query, only matching records are being displayed. The pipe `haku` is used for search queries from the data and the pipe `sivutus` is used for paginating the data.

The bug in the code is that the function `sortByField()` doesn't sort the data by field if the `table` has pipes `| haku:postitoimipaikka | sivutus:sivu` attached to it.

Once I remove the pipes from the table, the `sortByField()` function operates properly.

This works:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ottoautomaatti of ottoautomaatit">
```

This doesn't work:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ottoautomaatti of ottoautomaatit | haku:postitoimipaikka | sivutus:sivu">
```

sivu.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="postitoimipaikka" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Postitoimipaikka</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="postitoimipaikka" [(ngModel)]="postitoimipaikka"
      placeholder="Postitoimipaikka"> </div>
</div>

<p>Löytyi {{ ottoautomaatit | lukumaara:postitoimipaikka }} hakutulosta.</p>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="edellinen(sivu)">Edellinen</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="seuraava(sivu)">Seuraava</button>
</div>

<br><br>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th (click)="sortByField('sijaintipaikka')">Sijaintipaikka</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('sijaintipaikan_tyyppi')">Sijaintipaikan tyyppi</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('postinumero')">Postinumero</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('postitoimipaikka')">Postitoimipaikka</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('kohteen_osoite')">kohteen_osoite</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('aukioloaika')">Aukioloaika</th>
      <th (click)="sortByField('aukioloaika_lisatiedot')">Aukioloaika (lisatiedot)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let ottoautomaatti of ottoautomaatit | haku:postitoimipaikka | sivutus:sivu">
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.sijaintipaikka }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.sijaintipaikan_tyyppi }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.postinumero }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.postitoimipaikka }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.kohteen_osoite }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.aukioloaika }}</td>
      <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.aukioloaika_lisatiedot }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

sivu.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { OttoautomaatitService } from '../ottoautomaatit.service';
import { ottoautomaatti } from '../ottoautomaatti.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sivu',
  templateUrl: './sivu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sivu.component.css']
})
export class SivuComponent implements OnInit {

  postitoimipaikka: string;
  ottoautomaatit: ottoautomaatti[] = [];
  sivu: number;
  lukumaara: number = 0;

  lastSortedByField;
  ascendingOrder = true;

  constructor(
    private reitti: ActivatedRoute,
    private reititin: Router,
    private service: OttoautomaatitService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.haeKaikki().then((data) => {
      this.ottoautomaatit = data;
    })

    this.reitti.params.subscribe(parametrit => {
      this.sivu = +parametrit.sivu;
    })
  }

  edellinen = (sivu: number) => {
    if (sivu - 1 < 0) {
      this.reititin.navigateByUrl(`/sivu/0`);
    } else {
      this.reititin.navigateByUrl(`/sivu/${sivu - 1}`);
    }
  }

  seuraava = (sivu: number) => {
    this.reititin.navigateByUrl(`/sivu/${sivu + 1}`);
  }

  sortByField(field) {
    if (this.lastSortedByField === field) {
      this.ascendingOrder = !this.ascendingOrder;
    }
    else {
      this.lastSortedByField = field;
      this.ascendingOrder = true;
    }

    if (this.ascendingOrder) {
      this.ottoautomaatit = this.ottoautomaatit.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[field] < b[field])
          return -1;
        if (a[field] > b[field])
          return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    } else {
      this.ottoautomaatit = this.ottoautomaatit.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[field] < b[field])
          return 1;
        if (a[field] > b[field])
          return -1;
        return 0;
      });
    }

  }

}
```

ottoautomaatit.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ottoautomaatti } from '../app/ottoautomaatti.interface';

@Injectable()
export class OttoautomaatitService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  urli = "./assets/data.json";
  lukumaara: number = 0;

  haeKaikki = (): Promise<ottoautomaatti[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.urli).subscribe((data: ottoautomaatti[]) => {
        resolve(data);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }

  asetaLukumaara = (lukumaara: number) => {
    this.lukumaara = lukumaara;
  }

  haeLukumaara = () => {
    return this.lukumaara;
  }

}
```

haku.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ottoautomaatti } from './ottoautomaatti.interface';
import { OttoautomaatitService } from '../app/ottoautomaatit.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'haku'
})
export class HakuPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private service: OttoautomaatitService) {}

  transform(ottoautomaatit: ottoautomaatti[], postitoimipaikka: string): any {
    let palautettavatAutomaatit: ottoautomaatti[] = [];

    if (postitoimipaikka) {
      palautettavatAutomaatit = ottoautomaatit.filter(o => o.postitoimipaikka.includes(postitoimipaikka.toUpperCase()));
    } else {
      palautettavatAutomaatit = ottoautomaatit;
    }
    this.service.asetaLukumaara(palautettavatAutomaatit.length);
    this.service.asetaLukumaara(palautettavatAutomaatit.length);
    return palautettavatAutomaatit;
  }

}
```

sivutus.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ottoautomaatti } from './ottoautomaatti.interface';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sivutus'
})
export class SivutusPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(ottoautomaatit: ottoautomaatti[], sivu: number): any {

    let data: ottoautomaatti[] = [];
    let indeksi = 0;
    let per_sivu = 100;

    for (let ottoautomaatti of ottoautomaatit) {
      if (indeksi >= (sivu * per_sivu) && indeksi < (sivu + 1) * per_sivu) {
        data.push(ottoautomaatti);
      }
      indeksi++;
    }

    return data;

  }

}
```

I am expecting to be able to click on a table header and then sort the data in either ascending or descending order *and* also paginate the data and use the search function.

The actual result is that only one of the following functionalities in the app work successfully, not both:

- search functionaly throught pipe `haku` and pagination functionality through pipe `sivutus`
- sorting functionality through template function `sortByField()`

Comment: Pipe can only works on what input it gets, passing multiple pipes means that the output of the first pipe goes as input of second pipe.

Have you tried with single pipe?

Comment: Using just a single pipe works well, but how do I use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe can only works on what input it gets, passing multiple pipes means that the output of the first pipe goes as input of second pipe.

So Inorder for your pipe to work you should return array and wrap around it like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698908/multiple-pipes-simultaneously-in-angular-2)