# Chain custom pipes in Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am aware you can use custom pipes in components like so..

```
// ...
import { CoolPipe } from './cool.pipe';

// ...
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _coolPipe: CoolPipe) {}

  pipe(value) {
    return this._coolPipe.transform(value);
  }
}
```

but how can you chain pipes?

In an angular html component you can do the following

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filter: filters | order: order">
</div>
```

Is there an equivalent you can use in an angular component??

**I am aware I can do this in the html component, but I would like to do this in the component.ts file**

The only way I can think of doing it would be

```
pipe(value) {
   let newValue;
   newValue = this._filterPipe.transform(value);
   newValue = this._orderPipe.transform(value)
   return newValue;
}
```

Would something like this work and is this the best way to do it?

My use case is as follows

I have 3 pipes I have created `filter`, `search`, `order`

now in my **component.html** I have the following scenario

```
<div *ngIf="(items | filter: filter | order: order | search: searchTerm).length === 0 && value && !otherValue"></div>
```

now this clutters my html component so I would like to move this logic into my **component.ts** file into a function that returns either `true` or `false`

is this possible...

Comment: Relative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698908/multiple-pipes-simultaneously-in-angular-2 also relevant: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785880230/11/ch11lvl1sec67/chaining-pipes

Comment: @mwilson this does not even come close to being relevant to my question...

Comment: It does. You are wanting to run multiple pipes but in a sequential manner. Both links describe how you can run multiple pipes as well as (some) discussion on chaining (which is specific to your question)

Comment: @mwilson I know very well you can chain pipes in angular html markup, my question is how can you chain pipes in the typescript component?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: @mwilson you dont understand I am fully aware I could be doing this logic in my component.html file I want to do it in the component.ts file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195164/discussion-between-mwilson-and-smokey-dawson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a util(Courtesy: [Andy Van Slaars](https://vanslaars.io/post/create-pipe-function/)), something like this:

```
const _pipe = (f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args))
export const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce(_pipe);
```

Then, use it in your TS like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UpperCasePipe } from './upper-case.pipe';
import { LowerCasePipe } from './lower-case.pipe';
import { DasherPipe } from './dasher.pipe';
import { pipe } from './pipe.util';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {
    const { transform: upperCaseTransform } = new UpperCasePipe();
    const { transform: lowerCaseTransform } = new LowerCasePipe();
    const { transform: dashTransform } = new DasherPipe();
    console.log(pipe(
      upperCaseTransform,
      lowerCaseTransform,
      dashTransform
    )(this.name));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!